# Add Class to different html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having difficulty applying a class to a different page. Here is the scenario: I have a single page that I'm designing that loads external pages onto that page based off a link click in the menu. With this, I would like to incorporate a 'theme' button that when selected, changes from light to dark theme. The issue I'm running into, is even calling the class in the script, will change the background of that class, but won't change any of the font in the external page being displayed and there is also a white border on the object tag.

**Question is, how do I remove the white border in the object tag and affect the font tags (h1, h2, p, li, a, etc) on the page being loaded in the object tag?**

Here is the code for the script below. The external page is identified by the "ex_object" class:

```
<script>
$('#darkend').click(function(){
$('html').toggleClass("dark");
$('.ex_object').toggleClass("dark");
$('#darkend').hide("slow");
$('#lightend').show("slow");
$('#nav-toggle-header').css('color','#fff');
$('.wrapper').css('background','rgb(32,32,32)');
$('.sidemenu-info').css('background','rgb(32,32,32)');
});

$('#lightend').click(function(){
$('html').toggleClass("dark");
$('.ex_object').toggleClass("dark");
$('#darkend').show("slow");
$('#lightend').hide("slow");
$('#nav-toggle-header').css('color','#000000');
});

$('#nav-toggle-header').click(function(){
$('.wrapper').show('slow');
$('#sidebar').show('slow');

});

$('#nav-toggle-menu').click(function(){
$('.wrapper').hide('slow');
});
</script>

<div class="wrapper">
<nav id="sidebar">
<section data-accordion>
<section id="menu_accordion" data-control>DROP MENU</section>
<div data-content>
<a href="#" class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-1"><li id="menu_accordion_sub"><span>TEST</span></li></a>
</section>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="main">
<div id="content">

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
<object data="Pages/TEST.html" class="ex_object"></object>          
</div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.tab-link').click(function(){
var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

$('.tab-link').removeClass('current');
$('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
$(".wrapper").hide("slow");

$(this).addClass('current');
$("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
})

});
</script>
```

Comment: Post a more complete code sample to CodePen or similar.

Comment: what's the issue with the code sample? That is a script that when a button is clicked, it toggles theme from light to dark. What do you need?

Comment: We have no idea how you're loading the external content that you're trying to manipulate.

Comment: I can't really load it to CodePen because depending on the link click it will display a different page. The 'loading' portion of the external page is not an issue. It loads with no problem. But I will show you a code example in the edit above.

Comment: it is added above.